How to prove regime switching is not happening in parameters from data
Generally in economics/finance autoregressive models features regime switching in both parameters and volatility. In my case my data is giving a rough indication that regime switching in parameter is not a feasible option, or in other words only one kind of regime exists for the parameter. How can I prove it formally that only one kind of regime exist for parameter using for my autoregressive model from the data?

Hi: I didn't study it carefully but this looks useful. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104324/strucchange-package-on-arima-model
